# I need to pull from two tables into a loop and match the data

Tags: php, mysql

Please forgive me if I'm going about this the wrong way I don't have much experience in PHP development.

I need to list some real estate listings on a page, which is easy enough, but where I'm having trouble is trying to match them with the proper image. The images are stored on my server and I have the file path saved in one table and all the property info stored in another table.

This is what I have right now and it kind of works.. except for it is showing each listing twice. Once with pic once with out.. I know there has to be a much better way then this..

```
<?php 
  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name, documents_main WHERE show_listing='1' and user_type='1'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  // Start looping rows in mysql database.
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
     $payment = $rows['price'] * .09 / 12;
     $path =    $rows['path'];
     $id =  $rows['id']; 
     $note_id = $rows['note_id']; 
?>

<div class="row clearfix">
   <div style="width: 120px; float: left;">

<?php 
  if($note_id == $id){
    echo "<img src='$path'>";
  } else {
    echo "";
  }
?>

   </div>
   <div style="float: left;">
<? echo $rows['prop_city']; ?>, $<? echo $rows['price']; ?>$<? echo round($payment); ?> 
   </div>
</div> 

<?
// close while loop
}
?>
```

I can post the tables if that is helpful.

Comment: Look at using a JOIN for your tables.

Comment: So right now you are doing a Cartesian join between the two tables, Can you talk about what the relationship is between the two tables (i.e. which column(s) relate one table to the other) such that a join condition can be specified?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @dagon The query shows `... FROM $tbl_name, documents_main ...` that is a Cartesian join of those two tables.

Comment: Another word of advice is to not use `SELECT *` if you don;t need all the fields. You are just wasting badnwidth and memory in doing so.  Instead specifically select the fields you want to receive.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back I will read up on the articles you sent me.

Comment: The relationship between the tables is the id of the properties are stored as note_id in the document table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using two tables in your query, there should be a column in the second table linking the row to a row in the first column

Once you identified this field, write your query like this :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name, documents_main WHERE show_listing='1' and user_type='1' and  $tbl_name.FIELD_TO_BE_DEFINED = documents_main.ANOTHER_FIELD_TO_BE_DEFINED";
```

Or :

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name inner join documents_main on $tbl_name.FIELD_TO_BE_DEFINED = documents_main.ANOTHER_FIELD_TO_BE_DEFINED WHERE show_listing='1' and user_type='1'";
```

Comment: This worked! However I will go back through my code and clean it up.